# Is there a way to directly convert the elements of a list taken from a split string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, type-conversion

Let's say I have taken this line as input
`n='3.4 5.9 4.76 1.0'`

I want to split it into a list and convert each element to a float. Here's how I would do that

```
nlist = n.split()
for i in range(nlist):
    nlist[i] = float(nlist[i])
```

This works fine but I was wondering, out of curiosity, if there was a way to save each element of the list as an actual number to avoid doing the second cycle and "manually" convert each element.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. You can `map` each item to a float then use `list` to convert the resulting map to a list:

```
nlist = list(map(float, n.split()))
```

You can do a list comprehension which is more Pythonic I think:

```
nlist = [float(i) for i in n.split()]
```

Edit: I just realized that you are trying to avoid second iteration. As Sayse mentioned [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65900725/9608759) if you really want to avoid second iteration, you will need to process your string character by character and create your own string. This is more costly than list comprehension so it's better to avoid doing something like that.

Answer (score 2):

There is but it'd involve iterating over the characters of the string and building up a substring till you get to a space then casting that to a float. There isn't any other way to do this without iterating twice

```
curr_word = ""
floats = []
for c in n:
    if c == " ":
        floats.append(float(curr_word))
        curr_word = ""
        continue
    curr_word += c
if curr_word:
    floats.append(float(curr_word))
```

Its far more efficient to use your current approach or a list comprehension

Comment: I don't think it's faster than list comprehension.

Comment: @Asocia - Updated but the code wasn't important here, the question was about " avoid doing the second cycle" so whether a list comprehension is faster or not is irrelevant and doesn't answer the question

Comment: I'm talking about this: *"Its far more efficient to use your current approach or a list comprehension"* Both of the solutions are `O(N)` it doesn't matter if you iterate 2 times or 10 times. It's constant and doesn't matter.

Comment: @Asocia - Ah I see I misunderstood your original comment but think you're misinterpreting that, the O(N) doesn't factor in the processing involved within the code, building up your own strings is going to be far more costly than `split`

Comment: I got your point. So you are sharing a way of doing the same thing in a slower way? Because you are creating strings here.

Comment: @Asocia - I'm sharing the *only* way to do something. The question asked how to avoid the second cycle (the two being splitting and then iterating over with a for loop). The only way to do that is to manually split it yourself and then process an element that has just been split

Comment: Oh, you are right. OP specifically asks for avoiding second iteration and I missed it. My bad :/

Answer (score 1):

### Using Eval ## --> [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Eval will automatically convert the string to a Float Data type. Then how you iterate it, with a list comprehension, a function call or a for loop it doesn't really matter.

```
n='3.4 5.9 4.76 1.0'

nlist = [eval(n_) for n_ in n.split()]
for i in nlist:
    print(type(i))
```

### Output

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
```

### **Using List comprehension**

```
n='3.4 5.9 4.76 1.0'


nlist = [float(n_) for n_ in n.split()]
print(nlist)
```

**Output**

```
[3.4, 5.9, 4.76, 1.0]
```

---